# I am unable to set the width and height of the image using unsplash

Tags: html, css

[This is the html code...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcRER.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7ffC.png)

I tried multiple times changing the width...re-started VS-code multiple times but still im am un able to change the width. It gives a random size every time I refresh the page

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The link you are using for the image source tells everything.

```
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/300x300" alt=""/>
```

- In the url there is "random" that means the image will be served randomly
- 300x300 refers to image width and height

If you want an image with a different width and height then change those values from the url. For example: If you want an image with 900px width and 600px height then the url would be:

```
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x600" alt=""/>
```